How to increase volume with delay
which library i have to use or how to implement it in my SwifUI app.
i used AVKit, AVFoundation, MediaPlayer to manage audio and volume
but it not increase volume although decrease volume after 10 sec and
get runtime error:

<kbd>WARNING: AVF context unavailable for SYSTEM</kbd>

struct CustomPopUpView: View {
  
    import SwiftUI
    import AVKit
    import AVFoundation
    import MediaPlayer
    
    @State var audioplayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    private func increaseVolumeWithInterval() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
            increaseVolume()
            self.increaseVolumeWithInterval()
        }
    }
    
    private func increaseVolume() {
        let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
        
        if let slider = volumeView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider {
            let currentVolume = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
            let newVolume = min(1.0, currentVolume + 0.1)
            slider.value = Float(newVolume)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View { 
        VStack {
            //code for design
        }
        .onAppear() {
            increaseVolumeWithInterval()
        }
    }
}


Note you should not have import SwiftUI etc... inside your CustomPopUpView.
Also see the important MPVolumeView note, You can’t change the volume or choose a route with this class while testing in the Simulator. These abilities only work on a device.

Your function increaseVolumeWithInterval has a recursive call to itself. That doesn't look right.
